# $\text{Res}((5z^{9}+z^{11})\text{cos}(\frac{1}{z^3}),0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\cdot $ **Calculate :** $\text{Res}((5z^{9}+z^{11})\text{cos}(\frac{1}{z^3}),0)$

---

First, the singularity at $z_0=0$ is irremovable because the lim of $\text{cos}(\frac{1}{z^3})$ doesn't exist.

So the only way to calculate $\text{Res}((5z^{9}+z^{11})\text{cos}(\frac{1}{z^3}),0)$
would be by the Laurent series,
$$(5z^{9}+z^{11})\text{cos}(\frac{1}{z^3})=\Bigg(5z^{9}+z^{11}\Bigg)\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{2z^6}+\frac{1}{4!z^{12}}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n!}\bigg(\frac{1}{z^3}\bigg)^{2n}\Bigg)$$

But I don't see how that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue is $\frac1{24}$. Indeed, the residue of $5z^9\cos\left(\frac1{z^3}\right)$ at $0$ is $0$, since that's the coefficient of $\frac1z$ in the Laurent series of $5z^9\cos\left(\frac1{z^3}\right)$ centered at $0$, which is$$5z^9-\frac52z^3+\frac5{4!}\frac1{z^3}-\cdots$$whereas the coefficient of $\frac1z$ in the Laurent series of $z^{11}\cos\left(\frac1{z^3}\right)$ centered at $0$ is $\frac1{24}$, since this series is$$z^{11}-\frac12z^5+\frac1{24}\frac1z-\cdots$$

Comment: I didn't know about that, so if $g$ is the sum of  $2$ function and I can write them as Laurent expansions, the residue is the $a_{-1}$ term of both series ? What if they don't agree ?

Comment: The residue is the **sum** of the residues of those two functions. Since one of the residues is $0$ and the other one is $\frac1{24}$, the residue of your function is $0+\frac1{24}=\frac1{24}$.

Comment: Oh, now I get it, thanks!

Comment: The $z^2$ term in the Laurent series of $z^9\cos\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)$ should be a $z^3$.

Comment: @Enforce I've edited my answer. Thank you.